# Getting the same result from Ruby as Javascript for bitwise XOR

Tags: javascript, cryptography, web-scraping, crc32

In Ruby:

```
-1104507 ^ 3965973030 => -3966969949
```

In Javascript:

```
-1104507 ^ 3965973030 => 327997347
```

Someone asked a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898998/bitwise-or-in-ruby-vs-javascript) but the answer just pointed to a wrapper for Closure.  I need a way to get the same answers from Ruby as I get for JavaScript so I can port this code over.

I need a way of being able to get the JavaScript result from any `A ^ B` in Ruby for any integers `A` and `B`.

Comment: You'll need to use [a bignum library which supports bitwise XOR](https://github.com/justmoon/node-bigint), or write your own.

Comment: Um, no.  Don't need bignum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two *are* the same result, modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.  In Ruby you could `& 4294967295` to make the result the same as in Javascript.

To cover all the cases, you need to take into account that Javascript considers binary values to be *signed* 32-bit integers.  Ruby on the other hand will produce *unsigned* 32-bit integers from the `& 4294967295` operation.

So, in Javascript simply:

```
c = a ^ b
```

To get the same thing in Ruby:

```
c = (a ^ b) & 4294967295
c -= 4294967296 if c > 2147483647
```

Comment: what about `332763 ^ 2714866558`.  This one gives `2715058341` in ruby and `-1579908955` in JS.  And if you do `2715058341 & 4294967295` it's still `4294967295`

Comment: You mean it's still 2715058341.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark Adler for the initial tip, I think this is the way to do it algorithmically:

```
max_32_int = (2**32)

c = a ^ b

if c > (max_32_int/2)
  c = c - max_32_int
elsif c < -(max_32_int/2)
  c = c + max_32_int
end
```

Comment: You only need one `if`.  See my answer.

Comment: well, yours has `&` and `-`. Mine uses `+` and `-`.  Same number of operators, no?

Comment: `if` statements slow things down since they mess with the look-forward execution units.  Even if you had more operators, but fewer `if`'s, that would be a win.  So one less `if` and the same number of operators is definitely a win.  I should see if I can get rid of the remaining `if` with more operators.

Comment: Not that that really matters much, since ruby is an interpreter.